# Chromium - Error while building gradle for Android Studio

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, gradle, chromium

I am trying to build Chromium for Android on an Ubuntu 16.04(LTS) machine as an Android Studio project.

I have followed all the instructions from below url: this is successfully done

> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md#Installing-and-Running-Chromium-on-a-device/

and then to create the Gradle for android studio, I followed the below.

> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_studio.md

and when I hit the below command in terminal. I got the below error.

```
build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py --output-directory out/Debug
```

**Error**:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py", line 955, in 
>   main()  File "build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py", line 860, in
>   main    build_vars = _ReadPropertiesFile(os.path.join(output_dir,
>   'build_vars.txt'))  File "build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py",
>   line 111, in _ReadPropertiesFile    with open(path) as f: IOError:
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/home/user/chromium/src/out/Debug/build_vars.txt'

Please, anyone, guide me to fix the error.

Answer (score 3):

check your build_vars.txt file path

> ~/code/chromium_80.0.3987.132/src$ find -name build_vars.txt
>
> ./out/**Default**/build_vars.txt

change the command to

> ./build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py --output-directory
>   out/**Default**/